# External Style Sheet error in the codeigniter framework php?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, frameworks

i put this code in the `search.php` one of my view pages and i had an external style sheet

i called it inside that file using

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />
</head>
```

but not working how can i solve that problem???
but if i use

```
include('mystyle.css');
```

it works but i wanna use the first code how can i use it correctly???

Answer (score 0):

you likely have the wrong path, try:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/mystyle.css" />
```

Comment: it gives that `Fatal error: Call to undefined function base_url() in C:\xampp\htdocs\msite\application\views\search.php on line 5`

Comment: is it defined in your application's config file?

Answer (score 0):

also check whether you loaded the URL helper. This can be done in application/config/autoload.php so that it is always loaded. Or, by putting $this->load->helper('url'); in the respective method.

Without loading the URL helper you cannot use the base_url function.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify this even further, you should use the [link_tag()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html#link_tag) function that is built in to CI's HTML helper.

Load the helper either in your `application/config/autoload.php` or manually like this:

```
$this->load->helper('html');
```

Then you can just use this for your stylesheet links:

```
link_tag('mystyle.css');
```

This assumes that the file is located next to your `index.php`, but its best to put these in a sub directory, just make sure that your `.htaccess` file (if you are using one) allows the sub directory to be accessed directly. So it might end up looking like this:

```
link_tag('public/css/mystyle.css');
```

Aside, you can use `site_url()` instead of `base_url()` if you have loaded the url helper. It's actually more useful and looks cleaner IMO, because it accepts arguments while base_url() does not.

```
<?php $this->load->helper('url'); ?>

<link href="<?php echo site_url('mystyle.css'); ?>" /> // Will Work
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>'mystyle.css'" /> // Will Work
<link href="<?php echo base_url('mystyle.css'); ?>" /> // Doesn't work
```